# How do you replace a file name prefix in bulk with a bash script?

Tags: bash

What I've managed to do so far is append it.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *
do 
mv "$f" "File${f##/}"
done
```

File names consist of 3 random letters followed by 3 numbers. I need to replace the 3 letters with "File".

Comment: My standard comment: please *always* use `mv -n` or `mv -i` for any bulk move/rename like this, to prevent files from being silently and irreversibly overwritten in case of name conflicts, bugs, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you need to strip the three letters.

```
"File${f#???}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
newName=`echo $f | sed 's/^[a-z]\{3\}/File/'`
mv $f $newName
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *
do 
newName=File"$(echo "$f" | cut -c4-)"
mv "$f" "$newName"
done
```

Apparently I'm not supposed to comment to say thank you so I'll just add it here. Thank you, I'll use Ignacio's method.

Comment: `"$(echo "$f" | cut -c4-)"` is too complicated for Bash. Look at Ignacio's answer.